# Access custom context processor in django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-context

I am using django 1.9. In my settings file, I have added my apps custom context processor as such:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
                'my_app.context_processors.init',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

My context_processors.py file in my app is as such:

```
def init(request):
    profile = getattr(request, 'profile', None)

    if profile is None:
        profile_info = models.Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        profile = profile_info.user_type

    context = {
        "profile": profile,
    }

    return context
```

In my template, I am calling a helper file to get me the dictionary contents of my custom context file so I can get the users profile type. The helper file is as such:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def get_base_context(request):
    context = RequestContext(request).dicts[-1]   # Last context processor
    return context
```

In my template, when I try to retrieve my custom context, it returns nothing.

```
def view(request): 
    c = get_base_context(request)
    raise ValueError(c)
```

returns `{}`

I don't know what I am doing wrong but if anyone can point it out, I will appreciate it.

The way I want to use this in multiple templates is to get the profile type for the user that logged in.

For example:

```
{%if profile == "profile1" %}
    do something
{% elif profile == "profile2" %}
    do something else
{% else %}
    do something else 2
{% endif %}
```

So the reason I am trying to set up the profile via a template context is so I am not querying the user profile type for every view. There might be better ways to do it like perhaps creating a session but I wanted to go with this approach.

Let me know. Thanks

Comment: can you show what you are doing in the template? from where exactly are you calling get_base_context?

Comment: sorry I meant Im calling get_base_context in my views. So my views.py I have c = get_base_context(request)

Comment: def view(request): c = get_base_context(request)

Comment: What's not clear is why you need to call get_base_context at all in your views? These contexts are primarily for use by the template. How does this connect with your template? If you post your template's relevent section it might shed more light on this

Comment: @e4c5 I edited the question now, please take a look.

Comment: your template does not make use of any context processor